# yii2 custom validation in rule not working

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

How to implement custom validation in yii2?

My code in model rules is

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['product_price'], 'checkMaxPrice']
    ];
}

public function checkMaxPrice($attribute,$params)
{
    if($this->product_price > 1000) {
        $this->addError($attribute,'Price must be less than 1000');
    }
}
```

Anything else I have to do in view?

Answer (score 2):

Change Your Rule Property As:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['product_price'], 'checkMaxPrice' ,'skipOnEmpty' => false]
    ];
}
```

To know [Skip On Empty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in model looks OK. May be try

```
echo $model->getErrors();
```

in your controller.May be can help you.

Comment: How do I use this?